# how to get terminal to show root prompt in su

Tags: terminal, bashrc

I am logged into a (normal) user, but when I go su : password my normal promt goes into showing me this instead of what it should. how to I fix this?

```
ターミナル 10:15 AM (~) $ su
Password: 
\033[1;31mターミナル \@ \033[1;33m(\033[1;34m\W\033[1;33m) \033[1;31m$ \033[0m
```

I am using this case statment to change prompts depending on which term is fired up.

```
which_term(){
    term=$(ps -p $(ps -p $$ -o ppid=) -o args=);
    found=0;
    case $term in
        *terminator*)
            found=1
            export PS1="\@ \[\e[34;43m\]\w\[\e[m\]\\$ "
             if [ -f /usr/bin/screenfetch ]; then screenfetch; fi
            ;;
        *terminology*)
            found=1
            #  echo "terminology "  
            export PS1=" \[\e[31m\]%\[\e[35m\]\u\[\e[m\]\[\e[36m\]@\[\e[m\]\[\e[35m\]\h\[\e[m\] \[\e[32m\]\T\[\e[m\] \[\e[36m\]\w\[\e[m\]\[\e[31m\] >>$\[\e[m\]\`nonzero_return\` "  

            if [ -f /usr/bin/screenfetch ]; then screenfetch; fi
            ;;
        urxvt*)
            found=1
           # echo "rxvt " 
            #PS1='%\u@\h \@ \W >>\$' 
            export PS1="\[\e[33m\]%\[\e[m\]\[\e[31m\]\u\[\e[m\]\[\e[33m\]@\[\e[m\]\[\e[31m\]\h\[\e[m\]:\[\e[36m\]\@\[\e[m\]\[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[m\]\[\e[31m\] >>\[\e[m\]\[\e[33m\]\\$\[\e[m\] "
            #export PS1='\033[1;31mターミナル \033[1;33m(\033[1;34m\W\033[1;33m)\@\033[1;31m\$ \033[0m'
            ;;
        Eterm*)
            found=1
            export PS1="\d \@ Scooby-Doo\w\\$ "

           # if [ -f /usr/bin/screenfetch ]; then screenfetch -t; fi

            ;;
        aterm*)
            found=1
             export PS1="\d \@ Aterm\w\\$ "
             ;;
        roxterm*)
            found=1
             export PS1='% \@ \u@\h \W>>\$'
            ;;
        mrxvt*)
            found=1
            export PS1="\[\e[31m\]\T\[\e[m\]\[\e[33m\]@\[\e[m\]\[\e[31m\]\u\[\e[m\]\[\e[34m\]\h\[\e[m\]\[\e[35;42m\]\W\[\e[m\] "

            ;;

        ## Try and guess for any others
        *)
        export PS1='\033[1;31mターミナル \@ \033[1;33m(\033[1;34m\W\033[1;33m) \033[1;31m\$ \033[0m'

     if [ -f /usr/bin/screenfetch ]; then screenfetch -t; fi
            ;;
    esac
    ## If none of the version arguments worked, try and get the 
    ## package version
    [ $found -eq 0 ] && echo "$term " $(dpkg -l $term | awk '/^ii/{print $3}')    
}    

which_term
```

Answer (score 0):

What I believe is happening is that your `which_term()` function is executing in your personal login context. In that context all the prompt changes will work.  When you use the `su` (substitute user) command you are switching to a different user context.  In this case you will be invoking the `.bashrc` of the target user in the target context; in your case it is the default user, `root` invoking root's `.bashrc`.

If you wanted to override this you should do it manually.  For instance, if your user name were `userxbw`, then after the `su` command gives you a prompt, then executing `source ~userxbw/.bashrc` would source your personal `.bashrc` file.  However, this is a dangerous practice when running as root as you may have commands in your .bashrc that are dangerous when run as super-user.

Comment: their are Linux systems that have it so when a user issues su then logs in using the user terminal it automatically shows a [root@domain]# prompt. In a different color even, so why is it so hard to find the HOW TO on that?

Comment: Check out the `tput` command for color and the `bash` man page. PROMPTING section for command expansions.  `tput` lets me standardize color changing and get rid of the escapes.  For reference, my prompt is:

    `PS1='$(tput setaf 7)-- \u@\h:\w --$(tput sgr0)\n\!\$ '

Comment: I was curious as to what that (tput setaf 4) was used doing there, I'd never seen it before in connection to the prompt let lone anything else. Went to this created a prompt webpage I've used before, then seen it adding that to the prompt now, Where I'd never seen it doing that before. Struck me as odd. Fixed it too btw, brain freeze, change root sh to bash. gada' thanks for that insight about your prompt though.